# Dual boot using Windows boot manager does not work

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, system-installation

I am very new to Ubuntu and want to install it on a new partition besides Windows. I've followed the steps in this tutorial: http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2014/02/01/dual-boot-windows-8-or-windows-7-and-ubuntu-13-10-with-ubuntu-on-a-btrfs-filesystem/

And the installation itself worked like a charm. These were the steps I did:

1. Shrink partition size in Windows
2. Install ubuntu. As in the tutorial described I created three partitions:

   - Boot partition, logical, with 150 MB, EXT4 and mount point `/boot`
   - Swap partition, logical, with 2 GB
   - Main partition, logical, with 10 GB, btrfs and mount point `/`
3. The installation completed successfully (including GRUB2)
4. Now I booted back to Windows and installed EasyBCD
5. There I've added a new entry to Boot menu pointing to the 150 MB boot partition. The tool also recognizes this partition as "Linux".
6. When rebooting, the Windows Boot Manager appears and shows me the new Ubuntu entry as possible option

But when I select Ubuntu, GRUB is not showing up. Instead I see a cryptic error message (see below) that disappears quickly. I have no clue what I did wrong.

These are the error messages when Windows Boot Manager tries to boot from partition, which contains GRUB:

```
Try (hd0,0): NTFS5: No ang0
Try (hd0,1): NTFS5:
```

This disappears quickly and then:

```
Initialize variable space...
Starting cmain() ...
```

From that point on, nothing will happen. At this point I expected GRUB2 to show up.

This is what the harddisk looked like before I applied the new partitions. I could use `sdb1` as target for GRUB, but this would overwrite the Windows Boot Manager, correct? In case of an error I would not be able to boot Windows anymore, so I like to avoid this and use the Boot Manager of Windows instead.

[image: Available partitions on my SSD. Including the Windows Boot Manager partition.]

I tried boot-repair, but it does not work. I get this alert box at startup which says "/boot found.":

[image: boot-repair popup]

Comment: Can you please tell us _why_ you used EasyBCD?

Comment: It has been recommended in the tutorial. I know you can also change boot manager settings without extra tools somewhere in Windows, but this tool looked very handy. And indeed it is! Besides the fact, that it is not working ;-)

Comment: I see. I notice the guide references to version 13.10, which version did you attempt to install?

Comment: The latest LTS: 14.04

Comment: It may also be easier for you to use the GRUB as your main boot manager, and have Windows boot from that, instead of the Windows Boot Manager.

Comment: I've updated my question and added the reasons (mostly fear^^) why I would strongly prefer using Windows boot manager, first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25618/discussion-between-codingman-and-armin).

Comment: There is very little chance that you break your system if you do boot repair. It's super easy. See my answer

Comment: I've updated the error messages, which appear when Windows Boot Loader tries to load partition which contains GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely replace the Windows loader with GRUB. GRUB can manage both Windows and Ubuntu for you. This is simple, straight forward and error free way of dual booting in my experience. GRUB rocks!

I mentioned simple, and I mean it. All you have to do is insert your ubuntu Installation media, reboot, choose `Try Ubuntu without Installing`.

Now in the live mode, execute these commands, after connecting to internet:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Just choose `Recommended Repair` and follow the instructions. The end result will be that GRUB will be your Boot Manager, and with it you will be able to boot into both windows and any other linux distros you may install including Ubuntu.

Good Luck!

Source and reference: [Boot Repair: Ubuntu Docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work. When boot-repair starts, it shows the message:
"/boot found. Please check your settings." (freely translated)

Comment: What message, there is no link, come to chat.

Comment: Sorrz. I am struggeling with ubuntu live CD keyboard lazout </(

Comment: Then it runs. But windows is still booting, because I guess it is assuming that /boot must be repaired. Can you tell me what to setup in advanced settings?